# BigCommerce template - how can I get product search_keywords

Tags: templates, tags, keyword, bigcommerce

The product Admin has the section 'Storefront Details' with 'Search Keywords' tab.
Because of there is no any 'Tags' in BigCommerce product admin, then I'm using 'Search Keywords'.
How can I get product search_keywords on the product page using product template?

Not working for me:

```
<p>{{product.search_keywords}}</p>
```

or

```
{{#each product.search_keywords}}
<p>
    {{this}}
</p>
{{/each}}
```

I expect the list of 'Search Keywords' or possibly string with 'Search Keywords'.

There is also array[object] named 'tags' (Keywords by which this product can also be identified) here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/schemas#product .
But I don't know what the product tags are and where they are set for the product in the admin.